# Extension of alg closed fields = limit of smooth algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

In the proof of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0F0B, it is a claim that if $K/k$ is an extension of algebraically closed fields, then $K$ is a limit of smooth $k$-algebras. This is justified with https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07BV. However, this one is only valid if $K/k$ is separable. For our case this means $K=k$ so the Lemma has no content. Probably, it's a mistake, right?

Comment: What is your definition of separable extension?

Comment: @JérômePoineau probably I'm missing something... I thought an algebraically closed field has no nontrivial algebraic extension, and separable extensions are algebraic extensions... am I wrong? you mean that $K/k$ is always separable? I don't understand :(

Comment: A not necessarily algebraic extension is called separable, if it has a separable transcendence basis. That is, if $K/k$ is an extension of fields, $K$ is separable over $k$ if we can find $K/L/k$ with $L$ purely transcendental over $k$ and $K/L$ algebraic and separable.

Comment: @Mohan thank you... I am exposed... please delete the question :)

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030I

Comment: @Learner since there's no answer, you should be able to delete the question, no?

Comment: @Mohan's definition of a separable extension is correct only for finitely generated extensions. See the link given by Jérôme. For instance, if $k$ is a perfect field of char. $p>0$, the perfect closure of $k(x)$ is (of course) separable over $k$ but has no separating transcendence basis.